# Can I get multiple response from micro Service which will Query MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, executor

I have  Service which will give us response back by querying MongoDB on the basis of some parameter provided

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/custRef/{custRef}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> getServiceId(@PathVariable("custRef") String custRef) throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("Thread.currentThread().getName() :"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    String serviceId=//calling Mongo Service and getting the result 
    if(custRef == null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("No service id available for the given FO Id:" + custRef,HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(serviceId,HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I have another client which will call the above service by providing the proper parameter. I want to call the above service by using 10 threads. can I get the response back in same frequency from the above service or do I need to do any configuration on the server where above one is running

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50);

for (RouterInfo router : listOfcpeRouterInfo){
Future<String> serviceIDS = es.submit(new CalculationTaskA(router.getCustomerRef(), rieClient));
}

@Override
public String call() throws Exception {
    String currentThreadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
    log.info("##### [" + currentThreadName + "] <" + taskId + "> STARTIING #####");
    // System.out.println("[" + currentThreadName + "] <" + taskId + ">
    // Sleeping for " + sleepTime + " millis");
    // TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(sleepTime);
    //
    String serviceId = null;
    try {

        ///
        serviceId = rieClient.getObject(customerRef);
        log.info("serviceId for given foid: " + customerRef + " is " + serviceId);
    } catch (ParseException pe) {
        log.error("error while parsing Data", pe);
    }
    log.info("****** [" + currentThreadName + "] <" + taskId + "> DONE ******");
    return serviceId;
}
 calling above service
enter code here
 Inside  getObject I am doing below
ResponseEntity<String> response=restTemplate.exchange(this.serviceIdUrl+"/{foId}",HttpMethod.GET,entity,String.class,foId);
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, Spring Boot applications are multithreaded so your code sample

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50);

for (RouterInfo router : listOfcpeRouterInfo){ Future serviceIDS = es.submit(new CalculationTaskA(router.getCustomerRef(), rieClient)); }
```

would only be needed in your "Mongo" Service ***if*** asynchronous calls are to be made ***by*** the "Mongo" service.